# Not able to enter decimal values in a text box with type = text ,by using sendkeys in protractor

Tags: protractor, angular2-template

protractor

```
element(by.id('amt')).sendKeys('796.21');
```

Html code

```
<input _ngcontent-c34="" id="amt" maxlength="8" name="amt" pattern="^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$" required="" type="text" class="ng-touched">
```

Comment: `let $element = element(by.id('amt')); $element.click().then(() => $element.clear()).then(() => $element.sendKeys('796.21'));` If still no luck, make sure that used elementFinder actually locates your element (.isPresent()), and if so then post your config

Comment: the value entered in the textbox is 79621 ,it is not taking decimal value